# How to use CPasswordHelper in yii2

Tags: yii2, passwords, crypt

I am trying to encrypt a password using the PHP crypt function. In yii, it's recommended to use CPasswordHelper. When I call CPasswordHelper::hashPassword($password), it says Class 'common\models\CPasswordHelper' not found.

Please help?

Comment: CPasswordHelper is Yii 1 not Yii 2.

Answer (score 4):

To generate hashed password in Yii 2 use `security` component.

You can generate password hash with:

```
$hash = \Yii::$app->getSecurity()->generatePasswordHash($rawUserPassword);
```

To validate this password later on you can check:

```
if (\Yii::$app->getSecurity()->validatePassword($rawUserPassword, $hash) {}
```

Read more about this in [the Guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-security-passwords.html).

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice the version difference. Thank you